# Selenium won't execute script on page

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium (with python) to monitor a page periodically and save screenshots. This is done on a raspberry pi (armv6). Because of this, I'm using PhantomJS.

I'm monitoring certain elements, and since a raspberry pi isn't the fastest, I am executing a script with `driver.execute_script` to make the page smaller so that the screenshots aren't too big.

Unfortunately, when executing this script, the following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "`**path**`/bot.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.graphs(self.threads['graphs'])
  File "`**path**`/bot.py", line 93, in graphs
    self.driver.execute_script(`**script**`)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 543, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: \"script-src 'self' *.google-analytics.com\".\n","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"716","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:46451","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\": `**script**`, \"args\": [], \"sessionId\": \"69182660-cd69-11e7-b52d-9131a53fa749\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/69182660-cd69-11e7-b52d-9131a53fa749/execute"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

I've googled this error but I haven't been able to find a solution. Is this Selenium that's preventing me from executing this script or is a PhantomJS?

Thanks!

[edit]
Here's the code that's initializing the selenium webdriver:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--web-security=false'])
    self.driver.set_window_size(1070, 800)

    self.threads = {'check_login': threading.Event(), 'graphs': threading.Event()}

    self.login()

    self.graphs(self.threads['graphs'])
    self.check_login(self.threads['check_login'])
```

Comment: Would using `driver.set_window_size()` work for you instead? It looks like the exception that's being raised is a function of some sort of security policy on the actual web page--you may be able to get around this somehow, but using the `set_window_size` method would certainly be easier

Comment: I am setting the window size with self.driver.set_window_size(1070, 800) but this will still capture the whole page when I try to save a screenshot.

Comment: It is also no problem to execute the script with Chrome as webdriver. The raspberry however does not support a good chrome headless webdriver.

Comment: Ahh interesting. Well I don't have any internal knowledge of Phantom vs. Chrome. That said, you might be able to try Firefox, or crop the full screenshot as a workaround.

Comment: Can you share your code trial?

Comment: Added code. The problem however is obviously PhantomJS that's preventing me from executing a script on the page :\. Assuming that selenium is just an interface for webdrivers, why would PhantomJS prevent something like that?